# error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." during deploy solution from visual studio

Tags: error, solution-deployment

I create one share point solution  and two class library within that project,every library signed in properly,

but, while I deploy that on to share point site,various ways I tried like through power-shell, from Visual studio but every time I get following error

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Operation is not
>   valid due to the current state of the object.

I also tried to solution deploy on "no activation" mode but not helped

Answer (score 1):

First ensure the TimerJob service was running. If its running, try to restart it.